# Comunicação com Arduino via await async .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, arduino, async-await

Boa tarde!

Estou estudando a melhor forma de fazer a comunicação do meu projeto Web com uma placa de Arduino. Até o momento já consegui **ENVIAR** um comando de forma assíncrona, conforme o código abaixo:

```
//metodo para acender o led verde...
public static async Task<string> GreenLed(string ipCB)
{
    //acender luz verde...
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage request = await client.GetAsync("http://" + ipCB + "/5/on");
    }

    return "true";
}
```

Existe alguma maneira de **RECEBER** alguma informação do arduino da mesma forma, via URL? Essa é a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Está utilizando um shield WiFi ou Ethernet no seu Arduino? No para o shield WiFi pelo o que vi na documentação existe o WiFi.h que contém uma classe que funciona como um cliente HTTP, assim você consegue fazer requisições para o seu servidor .NET assim como você fez para o Arduino.

Comment: Como foi comentado, você precisa criar um endpoint pare receber as requisições na sua WebApi e implementar no código do Arduino para que ele envie essas mensagens para sua API. Recomendo que você edite a sua pergunta apresentando um [mcve]